# Force Oracle JDBC to use a proxy on a per-connection basis

Tags: java, oracle, networking, jdbc, proxy

I have a project at work where we receive a set of information to connect to an Oracle database (user, password, connection string, etc) and perform a given operation. One of the options however is to connect to the database through a network proxy (host, port, user and password) and as far as I can tell, there is no support for this on a per-request basis.

I've tried going through the Oracle documentation and information for Java and the most prominent suggestion is to set some variables (like http.) on the JVM, but that would make the settings common for all threads and these can change per operation. Going through the Oracle JDBC driver Java doc (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html#setConnectionProperties_java_util_Properties_) shows the complete set of connection properties I can set and there is no mention on network proxies, only proxy authentication which is unrelated for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle 18c JDBC driver supports specifying an HTTPS proxy as part of the connection descriptor:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-8D0ADAE6-B8EF-4E02-85E3-15C2509ACBD8

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to be what I need.